# iPhone and Application Settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to have a setting in an iphone app that uses a toggle switch to allow something to be turned on or off.  I have seen tutorials, but they only show how to do this in the iPhone's settings place.  I want this done inside the application.  Any guides, help advice.  I'm going for something similar to the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the UISwitch as accessoryView. This will look (almost?) exactly like in your picture.

Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UISwitch *mySwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc] init] autorelease];
        [mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        cell.accessoryView = mySwitch;
    }
    // configure cell
    UISwitch *mySwitch = (UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView;
    mySwitch.on = YES; // or NO
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Auto Connect";

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)switchToggled:(UISwitch *)sender {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"Switch %i,%i toggled", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UISwitch. Here's the very simple class reference guide.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Basically you can check its state by checking its "on" property.

```
if(mySwitch.on) {
   //do something here
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i'm trying to get it inside a table, or at least that is what it looks like it is in, by the look of the picture

Comment: The UISwitch is just a UIView subclass, so you can add this view to a custom tableView cell. Depending on where you want to add it in your tableView would depend on how you might design it into your code.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you're UITableView style is set to "Grouped"

Then, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, do something along these lines:

```
if (indexPath.section == kSwitchSection) {


    if (!randomControl) {
        randomControl = [ [ UISwitch alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(200, 10, 0, 0) ];
        [randomControl addTarget:self action:@selector(switchAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        randomLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,8,180,30)];
        [randomLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
        [randomLabel setText:@"My Label"];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [cell addSubview:randomControl];
    [cell addSubview:randomLabel];
}
```

Remember to release the UISwitch object later and to include code for setting it to on or off depending on what state it should be in.